# LaTeX command with optional argument to enclose parameter in parenthesis

Tags: macros, brackets

I want to define the following LaTeX command

```
\newcommand{\cost}[1][]{
   \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
     {c_N}
     {c_N((#1))}
  }
```

where the parameter `#1` is enclosed in parenthesis ( ) in the output. Unfortunately, the LaTeX output suppresses the parenthesis.  How do I make LaTeX not suppress the parentheses around the parameter?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. `\ifthenelse` and `\ifempty` are not standard LaTeX macros

Comment: The command does exactly what it's supposed to do: if you use `\cost` by itself, it produces `c_N`; otherwise `\cost[x]` produces `c_N((x))`. Are you using brackets for the argument?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\cost}[1][]{
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
        {$c_N$}
        {$c_{N(#1)}$}% with single parenthesis to the output
    }
    
    \cost  %no output
    
    \cost[] % no output
    
    \cost[x]
    
\end{document}
```

There were missing the `$...$` to use the inline math mode.

[image: x]

Comment: My impression is that the command `\cost` will be used in math mode, so adding `$` in the definition is not really good.

Answer (score 1):

When I do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\cost}[1][]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{c_N}{c_N((#1))}}
\begin{document}
    
    $\cost$  %no output
    
    $\cost[]$ % no output
    
    $\cost[x]$

    $\cost[\empty]$

\end{document}
```

, then I get:

[image]

As you can see two levels of parentheses occur in case `\cost`'s `#1` is not empty but contains some tokens.

---

Probably it is not about suppressing parentheses but about having parentheses in subscript?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cost}[1][]{c_{N\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{(#1)}}}%
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}
    
    $\cost$  %no output
    
    $\cost[]$ % no output
    
    $\cost[x]$

    $\cost[\{x\}]$

    $\cost[\empty]$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Probably it is not about parentheses but about curly braces?

(I suppose this because in the process of gathering macro-arguments one level of curly braces surrounding an entire optional argument/an entire (`]`-)delimited argument is stripped off, i.e., `$\cost[x]$` yields the same as `$\cost[{x}]$`.

Besides this curly braces of category 1(begin group)/category 2(end group) affect how things are processed/grouped/scoped while TeX is running but do not yield symbols/characters that are visible in the resulting PDF-file.)

If so, then you can do `\{`/`\}` or `\left\{`/`\right\}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cost}[1][]{c_{N\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{\{(#1)\}}}}%
\usepackage{xifthen}
\begin{document}
    
    $\cost$  %no output
    
    $\cost[]$ % no output
    
    $\cost[x]$

    $\cost[\empty]$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\cost[1][]{%
  \ensuremath{\if$#1$ c_N\else c_{N(#1)}\fi}}

\begin{document}    
    
$\cost$       \cost 
    
$\cost[]$     \cost[]    

$\cost[x]$    \cost[x]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]